# Transfer a file from one VM to another VM

Tags: ruby, vagrant

The problem is at subconfig1.vm.provision ... , any advices on how should i proceed ? After initializing the VM's Vagrant tells me that SSH faild to do the job, because connection is refused. I can make this work, but only manually, inserting the password, my big question here is how do I overpass the password to make this workflow automatically.

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

  config.vm.define "Machine2" do |subconfig2|

    subconfig2.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"
    subconfig2.vm.hostname = "Machine2"
    subconfig2.vm.network :private_network, ip: "172.16.10.101"
    subconfig2.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 4445, host_ip: "127.0.0.1"

  end

   #config.vm.provision "file", source: "~/.vagrant/machines/Machine2/virtualbox/private_key", destination: "/home/vagrant/ssh"


  config.vm.define "Machine1" do |subconfig1|
    subconfig1.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"
    subconfig1.vm.hostname = "Machine1"
    subconfig1.vm.network :private_network, ip: "172.16.10.100"

   # subconfig1.vm.provision "file", source: "~/.vagrant/machines/Machine2/virtualbox/private_key", destination: "/home/vagrant"

    subconfig1.vm.provision "shell", privileged: false, inline: <<-SHELL
      touch vagrantvm1-info
      ifconfig | grep "HWaddr" | cut -b 32-55 >> vagrantvm1-info
    #  ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no vagrant@127.0.0.1 uptime

      cp /vagrant/.vagrant/machines/Machine2/virtualbox/private_key ~/.ssh
      scp -P 2222 -i ~/.ssh/private_key vagrant@127.0.0.1:/home/vagrant/vagrantvm1-info /home/vagrant

    #  ssh vagrant@172.16.10.101
    #  scp vagrant@172.16.10.101:/home/vagrant/vagrantvm1-info /home/vagrant

   SHELL
  end




  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
# Display the VirtualBox GUI when booting the machine
   vb.gui = true
# Customize the amount of memory on the VM:
   vb.memory = "1024"
  end

  config.vm.provision "shell", privileged: false, inline: <<-SHELL
    apt-get install -y avahi-daemon libnss-mdns
    apt-get update
    apt-get install -y apache2
  SHELL

end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the private key so you can successfully login.

1. retrieve which private key is used

Generally the file is under `.vagrant/machines/<machine_name>/provider/private_key`

You can also run `vagrant ssh-config` to find out which private key is being used for all machines:

```
fhenri@machine:/Volumes/VM/vagrant/golang (master)$ vagrant ssh-config
Host default
  HostName 127.0.0.1
  User vagrant
  Port 2222
  UserKnownHostsFile /dev/null
  StrictHostKeyChecking no
  PasswordAuthentication no
  IdentityFile /Volumes/VM/vagrant/golang/.vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/private_key
  IdentitiesOnly yes
  LogLevel FATAL
```

In this case the private key is `/Volumes/VM/vagrant/golang/.vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/private_key`

2. copy the key in the VM.

Since you want to run the copy VM to VM, the origin VM needs to know the private key so it will connect to the destination VM.

Use a file provisioner or a copy file from a shell script to copy the private key used to login to destination VM into the origin VM.

3. scp using the private key - see [scp man page](http://www.linuxcertif.com/man/1/scp/en/)

   ```
   scp -i ~/.ssh/private_key \
   /home/vagrant/vagrantvm1-info \
   vagrant@172.16.10.101:/home/vagrant
   ```

The updated Vagrantfile I used to test this is the following

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

  config.vm.define "Machine2" do |subconfig2|

    subconfig2.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"
    subconfig2.vm.hostname = "Machine2"
    subconfig2.vm.network :private_network, ip: "172.16.10.101"
    subconfig2.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 4445, host_ip: "127.0.0.1"

  end

   #config.vm.provision "file", source: "~/.vagrant/machines/Machine2/virtualbox/private_key", destination: "/home/vagrant/ssh"


  config.vm.define "Machine1" do |subconfig1|
    subconfig1.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"
    subconfig1.vm.hostname = "Machine1"
    subconfig1.vm.network :private_network, ip: "172.16.10.100"

   # subconfig1.vm.provision "file", source: "~/.vagrant/machines/Machine2/virtualbox/private_key", destination: "/home/vagrant"

    subconfig1.vm.provision "shell", privileged: false, inline: <<-SHELL
      touch vagrantvm1-info
      ifconfig | grep "HWaddr" | cut -b 32-55 >> vagrantvm1-info
    #  ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no vagrant@127.0.0.1 uptime

      cp /vagrant/.vagrant/machines/Machine2/virtualbox/private_key ~/.ssh && chmod 0644 ~/.ss/private_key
      # make sure to accept the server keys
      ssh-keyscan 172.16.10.101 >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
      scp -i ~/.ssh/private_key /home/vagrant/vagrantvm1-info vagrant@172.16.10.101:/home/vagrant

    #  ssh vagrant@172.16.10.101
    #  scp vagrant@172.16.10.101:/home/vagrant/vagrantvm1-info /home/vagrant

   SHELL
  end




  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
# Display the VirtualBox GUI when booting the machine
   #vb.gui = true
# Customize the amount of memory on the VM:
   vb.memory = "1024"
  end

  config.vm.provision "shell", inline: <<-SHELL
    apt-get install -y avahi-daemon libnss-mdns
    apt-get update
    apt-get install -y apache2
  SHELL

end
```

Comment: I modified the way you told me, the only problem now is that it does not find the file:  File provisioner:
* File upload source file C:/Users/Cristian/.vagrant/machines/Machine2/virtualbox/private_key must exist

Comment: Just have `config.vm.provision "file", source: ".vagrant/machines/Machine2/virtualbox/private_key", destination: "/home/ssh"`; and make sure `private_key` exists under .vagrant/machines/Machine2/virtualbox/

Comment: If I mark this line out, and run the code, it works, I use vagrant ssh-configure, and i can see the private key in the folder, I can even acces it with cap. But no matter where I put the file provisioner in the code from vagrantfile, I can't acces it, vagrant says the file does not exist.

Comment: weird, can you make it in a shell provisioner, shell provisioner runs with ssh so the key must exist when you run it

Comment: Can you please give me a start, on what should I use in this shell provisioner, I am really stuck here ...

Comment: with vagrant, you have `/vagrant` folder available in VM to access all of you files from the project directory, so. add the line `cp /vagrant/.vagrant/machines/Machine2/virtualbox/private_key ~/.ssh` and it will copy the private key in your ssh folder in the VM

Comment: I re-posted everything I changed, it works, but in the end I got back to the first problem, the ssh does not recognize the private key, so it does not have access. If you spot the mistake please let me know, thanks nevertheless for your help :D

Comment: well are you sure you copied the correct key ? from host vagrant is using private key to ssh into the VM; copy this key in the VM and you will run ssh from VM to VM ... but first can you ping VM to VM ?

Comment: I changed the code form of the key multiple times in the hope of succes, nothin. Yes they can ping one another, tried from both of them, I am out of ideeas ...

Comment: I did what you told me, nothing different, after that I decided tot delete this syntax from both Machines subconfig1.ssh.insert_key = 'false' , and fails, giving me the next error, maybe this could help us figure out what is going on : Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root? , this error is on the cp /vagrant/.vagrant/machines/Machine2/virtualbox/private_key ~/.ssh line.

Comment: make privileged: false as said in previous comment for your provisioning

Comment: I did, edited again, you can see my last program. It is seted up as privileged: false. Hope I did everything fine

Comment: well, it should - replace the cp with `cp /vagrant/.vagrant/machines/Machine2/virtualbox/private_key /home/vagrant/.ssh` and scp command with `scp -P 2222 -I /home/vagrant/.ssh/private_key .....`

Comment: Same problem as above, unable to lock the administration directory. This is becoming frustrating :))

Comment: ok back to computer today ... made it work; the `privileged: false` should be used only for the 1st provisioning, the part about install package should remain normal, making the update Vagrantfile in answer

Comment: Yes, I figured out that yesterday, after I changed that, it still remains the same after, the ssh doesn't get access to the private_key, thanks for everything though, I already sent the problem to someone that has more experience, will come back with the result latter.

Comment: not sure why you say the ssh does not access the private key - in my case, with the Vagrantfile I provided, I am able to scp the vagrantvm1-info file into the Machine2 VM

Comment: https://ibb.co/c0mapQ I made a new vagrant file only with your code, still there is a problem.

Comment: page cannot be found

Comment: ok windows users - it does not respect the permission on copy - change `cp /vagrant/.vagrant/machines/Machine2/virtualbox/private_key ~/.ssh` to `cp /vagrant/.vagrant/machines/Machine2/virtualbox/private_key ~/.ssh && chmod 0600 ~/.ssh/private_key`

Comment: FInally, thank you mate, you are a real pro on this :D